# How to redefine an array in one statement?

Tags: c, arrays

One of my apps that I'm working on at the moment relies on a multi-dimensional array. So far, I've been using a static array that was defined once, in a style similar to:

```
float exampleArray[2][2] = {{1, 2},
                            {3, 4}};
```

However, I'd now like to redefine this array, and such arrays cannot be easily redefined. Unlike when I initialised the array, I'd have to redefine every element of this array separately, for example:

```
exampleArray[1][1] = 3;
exampleArray[1][2] = 0.5;
exampleArray[2][1] = 17;
exampleArray[2][2] = 2;
```

Since I'm working on a 17x17 array, the idea of having to do this doesn't really appeal to me! (And I don't really want to keep each array in memory at once, so three arrays or a three-dimensional array isn't the right way to go about this)

*I've looked into using a dynamic array instead. Theoretically, using a dynamic array, even I couldn't change everything in one go, I could free the memory for the old array, and then allocate memory for the new array.*

*However, I've not seen a way of defining a dynamic array in the style of the first example. Is there any easy way to define (or redefine) a dynamic array without directly manipulating one element at a time (i.e. in a similar fashion to my first example)?*

**EDIT:** See the suggestions below for methods that doesn't require dynamic arrays. Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: Define an other array and switch the pointers ?

Comment: Use some `for` loops to get each element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always copy one array to another using `memcpy`:

```
float exampleArray[2][2] = {{1, 2},
                            {3, 4}};

float newArray[2][2] = {{ 3, 0.5},
                        {17, 2}};

memcpy(exampleArray, newArray, sizeof(exampleArray);
```

Comment: Great suggestion! Thanks for the incredibly fast responses!